# Performing calculations on an html form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am fairly new to HTML & Javascript and I have been assigned a task to create a HTML form for a restaurant which allows the user to input their information for a booking. So far I have created the form for the website and validated each input field in order to ensure the correct information is entered into the necessary fields. However, I also need to enable the form to calculate a total price for the booking based on 2 details (number of people in the party & if the customer wishes to dine in the VIP area).

Here is the related html code thus far:

```
...    

<strong>Select Party Size:</strong>
<br>
<select name="party" id="party" onblur="validateSelect(name)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="1">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option value="2">2 People (£10)</option>
<option value="3">3 People (£15)</option>
<option value="4">4 People (£20)</option>
<option value="5">5 People (£25)</option>
<option value="6">6 People (£30)</option>
<option value="7">7 People (£35)</option>
<option value="8">8 People (£40)</option>
<option value="9">9 People (£45)</option>
<option value="10+">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>

...

<strong> VIP Area? </strong>
<br>
Yes (+£5) <input type="radio" name="hand" id="left" value="Yes"onblur="validateRadio(id)"/>
No <input type="radio" name="hand" id="right" value="No" onblur="validateRadio(id)"/>
<span class="validateError" id="handError" style="display: none;">Please specify whether you would like a table in the VIP area.</span>

...

<strong> Total booking cost based on party size & VIP selection: </strong>
```

For example, if the customer selects that there are 6 people in their party and they also wish to be seated in the VIP area, the total price displayed at the bottom of the page would be £35. I understand this can be performed in javascript so I would be very grateful if someone could show me how this can be done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(document).on('change', '#party', function(e) {
        $('#price').html(parseInt($(this).val()) + parseInt($('input[name="hand"]:checked').val()));
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', 'input[name="hand"]', function(e) {
        $('#price').html(parseInt($('#party').val()) + parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>Select Party Size:</strong>
<br>
<select name="party" id="party" onblur="validateSelect(name)">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="5">1 Person (£5)</option>
<option value="10">2 People (£10)</option>
<option value="15">3 People (£15)</option>
<option value="20">4 People (£20)</option>
<option value="25">5 People (£25)</option>
<option value="30">6 People (£30)</option>
<option value="35">7 People (£35)</option>
<option value="40">8 People (£40)</option>
<option value="45">9 People (£45)</option>
<option value="50">10+ People (£50)</option>
</select>

<strong> VIP Area? </strong>
<br>
Yes (+£5) <input name="hand" id="left" value="5" onblur="validateRadio(id)" type="radio">
No <input name="hand" id="right" value="0" onblur="validateRadio(id)" checked="" type="radio">
<span class="validateError" id="handError" style="display: none;">Please specify whether you would like a table in the VIP area.</span>

    <strong> Total booking cost based on party size <span id="price">0</span> VIP selection: </strong>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, the code you posted seems to run perfectly on here but when I try and implement it to my existing code the total cost doesn't increase from 0 when either the party size or VIP area is checked, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you used the HTML i posted? It has changes.